# Adding Extra 4GB Memory Module to 2X2GB

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard

Can i add a 4GB Ram Module to my Intel P55 Chipset Motherboard which already has 2X2GB Modules(4GB).Will this cause any issues like timing problem?

**UPDATE:
I have an intel DP55WB Board,it supports 16GB Ram.I have inserted two 2gb Sticks into Channel A DIMM0 and Channel B DIMMO.The 2 DIMM1 Slots are remaining.**

Comment: What is the model number of the actual motherboard?

Comment: First of all, you need to check if you have any free memory slots available to insert a new stick of RAM. If all available slots are already used up by the 2 memory modules, you can't upgrade without having to remove at least one of the 2 GB sticks.

Comment: @coolman - Check the motherboard's manual for supported memory configurations.  You will have to verify the configuration you want to use is supported.

Comment: @bobSmith1432 DP55WB is the model number

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that this should be fine and will work.

RAM will always work at the slowest component speed - so bear in mind that if you have 2*2GB(1600MHz) and 1*4GB(800MHz) - your RAM will all slow down to 800mhz, but you will still have 8GB of perfectly useable RAM.

Doing this will give a performance impact - but only a miniscule one which is far outweighed by massive performance increase of doubling your RAM.

Before you go purchasing, make sure you actually have a spare slot to stick the RAM in as well - I've seen people go out and buy, only to realise they didnt have a slot.  In your case, this would give 2GB+4GB=6GB, so you would still have an increase, but not as much as you hopes for.

Also, lastly, remember that if you are running windows x86 (32-bit) - you are limited by the OS to 4GB RAM, so you will need to install a 64-bit OS to get usage out of your RAM.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have an intel DP55WB Board,it supports 16GB Ram.I have inserted two 2gb Sticks into Channel A DIMM0 and Channel B DIMMO.The 2 DIMM1 Slots are remaining.

Comment: That is excellent advice. But if you're looking to get the best performance out of your machine (who isn't?) it'll do you good to check out [this SuperUser blog post](http://blog.superuser.com/2012/08/14/a-super-users-guide-to-memory-qotw-40/).

Comment: In that case coolman, add away.

Comment: Is there any compatibility that i need to look for?

Comment: Your board supports DDR3-1333/1066.  As long as you install these, you'll be fine

Comment: However, it's best that you match the new RAM modules so that they have the same (or similar) CAS latencies, voltage and frequency as your current sticks. You can check these values using [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html).

Comment: If you currently have DDR-1066 sticks, getting the faster DDR3-1333 sticks won't do you any good at all. The new sticks will work at DDR-1066 speeds. To check your RAM config, get CPU-Z and take a look at the [SPD tab](http://www.aussiepcfix.com/images/cpu-z.png)

Comment: @Fazer87 The Corsair model im looking for is 1600MHz.Will this cause issues?

Comment: @Vinayak It shows Bandwidth-PC3-10700(667MHz) in both the slots

Comment: PC3-10700 is DDR3-1333. [Some manufacturers round off to 667 MHz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR3_SDRAM#cite_ref-14). So what I'm saying is you shouldn't look at DDR3-1600 (PC3-12800) RAM sticks. That won't do you any good. Your board only supports upto DDR3-1333 (PC3-10600/PC3-10700) anyway.